# How to get data properties of class and object properties between 2 class in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have a ontology tourism.owl (format rdf/xml). There are some class (Tour, City, Hotel...). In Tour class, i have a data property "hasDate", Tour class is joined with City class using "hasCity" object property.
Ex: TourA hasDate "01-01-2001" and TourA hasCity London.

1. How to get "01-01-2001" (value of data properties)?
2. How to get object properties between 2 class? (Ex: Tour class and City class, result is hasCity)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very straightforward. Generally in SPARQL if you know the relationship between two concepts, you can just ask for:

> Which two concepts have this specific property?

It doesn't really matter if the property is an object property or a dataType property. For example, imagine in your ontology the URI is `http://www.co-ode.org/test.owl#` and you want to extract `hasDate`, then you just need to write:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/test.owl#>
SELECT ?subject ?object
    WHERE { ?subject :hasDate ?object }
```

And if you want to get an object property `hasCity`, then you simply write:

```
    PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/test.owl#>
    SELECT ?subject ?object
            WHERE { ?subject :hasCity ?object }
```